# How do I properly type nested React Navigation navigators?

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

For my top level navigator, I have:

```
type NavigationParamList = {
  Instances: undefined;
  Default: undefined;
  Settings: undefined;
  Compose: undefined;
};

const AppStack = createNativeStackNavigator<NavigationParamList>();

<NavigationContainer theme={NavTheme}>
      <AppStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Default">
        <AppStack.Screen
          name="Instances"
          component={InstancesScreen}
        />
....
```

But when I do something like:

```
navigation.navigate('Instances')
```

I get:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(...args: never): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(options: never): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get TypeScript to finally just be happy?

Comment: [mre] please? note: ts playground supports importing npm modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer, tho if possible please give more detail for the question. (More snippet of your code)

---

#### Whole code:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type RootStackParamList = {
  Profile: { userId: string };
};

const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function App(){
  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        initialParams={{ userId: user.id }}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

If you use `useNavigation` don't forget to put a typing:

```
import type { NativeStackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

type ProfileScreenNavigationProp = NativeStackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  'Profile'
>;

const navigation = useNavigation<ProfileScreenNavigationProp>();
```

Don't forget to also put the correct typing for your `Profile` component:

```
import type { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>;

function ProfileScreen({ route, navigation }: Props) {
  // ...
}
```

---

Read more info in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to TypeScript not being able to infer the correct type for the 'navigation' object. To fix this, you need to provide type information to the 'navigation' object so that TypeScript knows which screens are available for navigation